# Using Vector Drawable by drawing in Canvas

Tags: android, canvas, svg

- I have a imported an SVG into my project as Vector Drawable.
- I have my custom view

I know how to display a vector drawable using an ImageView by code (http://www.androidhive.info/2017/02/android-working-svg-vector-drawables/)
, which is described in several articles, but:

How can I draw my vectors using my custom view and by code with canvas ?
Is this possible to do. And if so, can someone give me a hint.

Comment: sure, use `Drawable#draw()` method

Comment: Perfect. Works. So easy, thanks.

Comment: sure, no problem

Comment: one thing, `VectorDrawabe` uses a `Bitmap` under the hood, so if your vector drawable has full screen bounds and you use multiple of them you can get into memory problems

Comment: Thanks for this hint, this changes my plan howto draw. Thanks for warning me.

Comment: but you could parse your VectorDrawable xml files like this: https://gist.github.com/pskink/dcc0db651e7443f247c0e9c9a40acc5a

Comment: Very very interresting. Thank you so much. Where do you have the PathParser Class from ?

Comment: ah, ok get it from `support-vector-drawable` package, it is only one file that can be copied to your project with no modifications

Comment: Thanks a lot, kind regards.

Comment: its android/support/graphics/drawable/PathParser.java and has only 750 lines with comments or simply get https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/graphics/drawable/static/src/android/support/graphics/drawable/PathParser.java

Comment: Helped me very much. Thanks.

Comment: sure, your welcome, and if you want to avoid that magic indexes in `TypedArray#get*` methods you would need to add your custom [declare-styleable](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html#customattr)

Comment: Ok Thanks. Such good support and hints should be payed.

Comment: yes, indeed, in CHF only ;-)

Comment: You can have CHF, I am from switzerland. No joke would donate if you have paypal .

Comment: thanks a lot, i have no paypal, give it on charity iinstead

Answer (score 2):

To do this you need to convert the vector to a bitmap as follows:

```
private fun getVectorBitmap(context: Context, drawableId: Int): Bitmap? {

    var bitmap: Bitmap? = null

    when (val drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, drawableId)) {

        is BitmapDrawable -> {
            bitmap = drawable.bitmap
        }

        is VectorDrawable -> {

            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                drawable.intrinsicWidth,
                drawable.intrinsicHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
            )
            
            val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
            drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
            drawable.draw(canvas)

        }
    }

    return bitmap
}
```

Then you can use the vector as a bitmap normally with your canvas:

```
  canvas?.drawBitmap(getVectorBitmap(context, R.drawable.ic_icon), 500f, 500f, canvasPaint)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to turn @pskink's comment into an answer as I'm not so advanced in android as to quickly realize what he meant. I had to read @Krishna's answer to understand. So credits to both of them.
Here it goes:

A vector drawable inherits `Drawable` that can be drawn directly into a canvas. First, get the drawable from the resources using an android context:

```
val drawable = yourContext.getDrawable(drawableId)
```

Then simply draw into the canvas with it. The next line tells the drawable to draw on the top left corner, with a size of 32x32 pixels:

```
drawable.setBounds(0, 0, 32, 32)
```

Finally draw it into the canvas:

```
drawable.draw(canvas)
```